# Stack rows of data using a single reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of football fixture dates in a matrix that I want to output in a single column. I've constructed a formula that does this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(HSTACK(B2:F2,B3:F3,B4:F4,B5:F5,B6:F6))
```

[image]

There are two problems, though:

1. I've referenced each row individually when I only want to reference the whole range but return the same results as shown. I have tried using BYROW for this but to no avail.
2. The empty cells are output as `00/01/1900` when I want these to be blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want blanks at all:

```
=TOCOL(B2:F6,1)
```

If you want to keep blanks:

```
=IF(TOCOL(B2:F6)=0,"",TOCOL(B2:F6))
```

or

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(B2:F6),IF(x=0,"",x))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please see before posting, when someone aslo has posted the same solution, also using 1 in `TOCOL()` excludes the blanks which is not intended in the post.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't see you posted same solution. It shows "answered x mins ago" with same x for both posts. It must be a matter of seconds

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B8</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IF(B2:F6="","",B2:F6))
```

---

You can also exclude the <kbd>IF( )</kbd> within <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd> but it would shows the blanks as `0`s while it can be hidden using custom formatting.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B8</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(B2:F6)
```

---

Custom formatting applied in the cells : `m/d/yyyy;;`. But you can use the firt approach as well.